# Does "efficiently monetizing" sounds awkward?

Tags: transitivity, parallelism

I'm improving a website and hope someone could help me see if the sentence below has any problem.  In particular, does "efficiently monetizing" sounds awkward?

> "It helps you acquire targeting users and efficiently monetizing, as well as rapidly occupying overseas market."

Comment: I don't understand what *any* of this means. It just sounds like a bunch of "industry buzz-words" randomly mixed up / strung together.

Comment: @user92151 I assume this is meant for a business website. What does it mean to occupy an overseas market?

Comment: I mean it can help customers acquire market share from foreign countries, but I don't know how can I make the sentence sounds professional

Comment: @user92151 "It can help acquire market share" sounds a lot clearer.

Comment: It's not only a bunch of marketing buzzwords, it doesn't actually parse. "It helps you ... efficiently monetizing". That doesn't work.

Comment: What in the world is a *targeting user* that you could acquire?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the comments! With your and Jasper's help, I changed the sentence to: " It provides innovative marketing solutions and traffic acquisition services that boost profitability. This is the ultimate platform taking your business go global". Please please let me know how can I improve it this time. Thanks again!

Comment: @user92151 -- Congratulations.  You should delete the word "go" from your revised second sentence.  "Taking your business global" provides the sense of motion that "go" tries to provide.  You might also want to put the word "for" between "platform" and "taking".

Comment: @Jasper You are the best man! It's a pleasure to meet you here, have a good night!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "efficiently monetizing" does sound awkward, for two reasons:

- "Monetizing" is a transitive verb that needs an object.  What is being monetized?
- There are three verb phrases after "you", and none of them have a causal or temporal relationship with the others.  Without such a relationship, the verbs should have parallel forms.  "Acquire" is not parallel with "monetizing" and "occupying".

There are other errors in the example sentence.  I have highlighted problems that were specifically asked about.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jasper! 

Should I just delete "efficiently monetizing" and change the sentence to "It helps you acquire targeting users and rapidly occupying overseas market"?                        
                                                                                                                               
How would you improve this sentence to make it sounds professional?

Comment: @user92151 -- No.  Making money for your client(s) is at the core of your [value proposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53114#53114).  Even if you delete "efficiently monetizing", your sentence is still grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @user92151 -- Consider focusing your business efforts on the parts of your business that you do very well, and hiring other people to do the parts that you are not good at (yet).  For example, you can hire a native speaker of English as either a "copywriter" or a "proofreader", and focus on the design and code of webpages.  Meanwhile, continue learning English.  When your English is good enough that you fully understand this comment and the [value proposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53114#53114) answer, you might be ready to write ad copy.

Comment: Got it! I appreciate your advice Jasper!